# regex for 2 digit numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex dons't include number:98,10 why?

```
    <script>
        var s = "asd asd 97 sasd3 54 asd98asd 10sasdal334";
        document.write(s,"<br> 2 digit numbers: ",s.match(/\b[0-9]{2}\b/gm));
    </script>
```

Comment: Because you're using word boundaries.  If you want to match two digit numbers, drop the boundaries.  Also, try learning regular expressions before using them.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sH1wA1/2 - remove the 2nd \b - It was almost done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not include 98 and 10 because you use: `\b`

> `\b` ... Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by an ASCII letter, digit, or underscore)